# Are Dylan and the Four Horsemen still wanted criminals?

Tags: plot-explanation, now-you-see-me

At the end of the movie *Now You See Me*, the three horsemen (excluding Jack) are on the run from the cops.

In the last scene, you can see Dylan in Paris, next to the other cop (the blonde lady) explaining to her what he did and why. She doesn't turn him in, but do the police know about what actually happened? What Dylan actually did? 
He basically told Thaddeus that he was the mastermind, but would they believe Thaddeus if he said so?

And are the four horsemen still wanted? Even Jack? The cops must still believe that Jack is dead, or do they believe Thaddeus's explanation about the car accident?

**Q**: Who's still a wanted criminal? Is it just Thaddeus who took the fall?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost everything is explained on the second movie of *Now You See Me*. But let's go through this by parts:

1. **Yes, they are still wanted criminals**

   They weren't caught, but hell yeah the police still wants them.  The second movie starts and Daniel as well as the other horsemen complain about being held "hidden" for so long.
2. **Nobody would have believed Thaddeus back then**

   Also in the second movie, when Dylan is caught, the cop (sorry, forgot his name) says "I knew it" when they find out Dylan's involvement with the horsemen. But that happens a long time foward from the first movie. Back when Thaddeus was caught, surely no one would have believed them. After all, *Thaddeus is a criminal*, right?  The Horsemen were gone after his imprisonment. There were no reasons to believe him.
3. **She doesn't turn him in because she likes him**

   I mean, it's obvious that there is some sexual tension between these two when the movie is in its mid-end. So I think she doesn't turn him in because the case is "over", she's never going to see him again, and she really likes him.
4. **Jack is given as dead**

   Nobody thinks he's alive besides the horsemen who know this for sure. But in the second movie, when Jack is revelead as alive, it is a great shock for everyone.
5. **No one believes Thaddeus and the Horsemen are all wanted, except Jack 'cause he's dead**

   Yes, no one believed Thaddeus. The guy was found with the money on his car. Sure it *looks* very much like a trap. But it's the police in the movie we're talking about, they believe Thaddeus is the mastermind behind the horsemen. And yes, the horsemen (all) are still wanted.